# How to connect proxy cluster

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm using com.microsoft.azure.kusto connect to kusto database for my project. However, my cluster is not in the format of <profile-name.region>. It's a proxy url (https://kusto.microsoft.com/). It doesn't seem to work and returns nothing. Just wondering does the library support connect to the proxy url?

Thank you.

Does the library support connecting to proxy url?

Comment: There is no such proxy url, where did you get it from? Take a look at your connection in the tool you are using.

Comment: The URL is https://kusto.aria.microsoft.com, and the error I'm getting is com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.exceptions.DataWebException: HTTP/1.1 403 The proxy was unable to access the provided cluster. My app was added to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the comment by @Anera above.

Regardless, you can provide the authentication token to the client from the outside, using either [AccessTokenTokenProvider](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-java/blob/master/data/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/data/auth/AccessTokenTokenProvider.java) or [CallbackTokenProvider](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-java/blob/master/data/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/kusto/data/auth/CallbackTokenProvider.java) class. The audience to issue the token for should be "https://kusto.kusto.windows.net"